# Getting set of values from array based on a condition

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript array as shown below

```
var userMale = [];
var userData = [
                {userId: "100", userName: "John", gender: "M"},
                {userId: "101", userName: "Emma", gender: "F"},
                {userId: "102", userName: "Alex", gender: "F"},
                {userId: "103", userName: "Sam", gender: "M"}
              ]
```

I need to get all userIds in to a different array based on gender condition, i.e. All males should be in userMale array

I have written below code to achieve that. It works, however, I am looking to avoid for and if loops

```
for(var i=0; i<userData.length; i++) {
    if(userData[i].gender == "M") {
        userMale.push(userData[i].userId);
    }
}

console.log("userMale: ", userMale);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to filter and project the elements onto `userId` at the same time, an approach using `Array.reduce` seems the best fit. See here:

```js
var userData = [
                {userId: "100", userName: "John", gender: "M"},
                {userId: "101", userName: "Emma", gender: "F"},
                {userId: "102", userName: "Alex", gender: "F"},
                {userId: "103", userName: "Sam", gender: "M"}
              ];
              
const convert = (data) => data.reduce((result, { userId, gender }) => {
  if (gender === 'M') {
    return result.concat(userId);
  } 
  
  return result;
}, []);   

var userMale = convert(userData);

console.log(userMale);
```

Comment: This is a better approach since it needs to loop once rather than twice as in Danijel's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var userData = [
                {userId: "100", userName: "John", gender: "M"},
                {userId: "101", userName: "Emma", gender: "F"},
                {userId: "102", userName: "Alex", gender: "F"},
                {userId: "103", userName: "Sam", gender: "M"}
              ]
              
let userMale = userData.filter(data => {
  return data.gender === "M"
})

console.log(userMale)
```

Comment: I just need userIds i.e. 100, 103 in the array. Not the entire data

Comment: Okay, you can append [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `let userMale = userData.filter(data => {
  return data.gender === 'M'
}).map((value) => {
 return value.userId;
});`

Answer (score 1):

All you need is using [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) function

```
var userData = [
                    {userId: "100", userName: "John", gender: "M"},
                    {userId: "101", userName: "Emma", gender: "F"},
                    {userId: "102", userName: "Alex", gender: "F"},
                    {userId: "103", userName: "Sam", gender: "M"}
                  ]

    let userMale = userData.filter(data => {
      return data.gender === "M"
    })

    let userFemale = userData.filter(data => {
      return data.gender === "F"
    })
```

Comment: I just need userIds i.e. 100, 103 in the array. Not the entire data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reject` of [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#reject)

`reject` returns the values in list without the elements that the truth test (predicate) passes.

```
var userMale = _.reject(userData, function(item){ return item.gender != "M"; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
var userData = [
  {userId: "100", userName: "John", gender: "M"},
  {userId: "101", userName: "Emma", gender: "F"},
  {userId: "102", userName: "Alex", gender: "F"},
  {userId: "103", userName: "Sam", gender: "M"}
];

function getMaleFemale ()
{
  // Create an array for each gender
  let male = [], female = [];
  
  // For each user, check if gender is F, if so, push id to female else to male
  userData.forEach( user => ( user.gender === 'F' ? female : male ).push( user.userId ) );
  
  // Return male and female
  return { male, female };
}

// Usage example
let { male, female } = getMaleFemale();

// Do something with male and female

console.log( 'male :', male );
console.log( 'female :', female );
```

Answer (score 0):

A concise version of [FK82's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210287/2206733).

```
let userMale = userData.reduce((result, user) =>
    user.gender === 'M' ? result.concat(user.userId) : result
, [])
```